# MBR is on wrong drive (USB) now windows/ubuntu won't boot w/out usb connected

Tags: grub2, usb, system-installation, windows-8, acer

I somehow installed Grub on my USB drive, now Windows/Ubuntu won't boot unless my USB drive is connected. How do I move the MBR to my laptop - internal HDD?

`Acer 64`; `Windows 8`; `Ubuntu 14.xx`

Comment: It depends on a number if issues. First, many BIOS allow which OS to boot. 32 or 64 bit ? EFI ? If your BIOS does not allow you to select which OS to boot, reinstall grub to the hard drive. You can do this manually or with boot-repair.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

Boot your pc from the HD.

Extract the usb drive.

Open a terminal. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install reinstall grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub-common
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub
reboot
```

This procedure is for non-UEFI bios.

For UEFI procedure is:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install reinstall grub-efi
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub
reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.

2 q's, if you please:
1- I can't figure out which bios (UEFI non-UEFI) I have- do tell.
2- I'm a bit scared to mess with grub, and was wondering if you knew the risks of my computer not booting after this procedure.
Thanks again.

Comment: Load gparted. Check the partition table of the hard drive.
If it is GPT and has a Efi partition as first partition is UEFI. If the partition tables is MSDOS, has MBR.

Comment: Partition table is MSDOS. But, gparted reports : (gpartedbin:3020): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it when it starts; there is an exclamation point after /dev/sda1/; and when I unplug the external hdd- after booting, Ubuntu stops working.
Here is a screen shot: ![https://www.anonimg.com/img/deae64e57a418631243b0d317a8d567e.png]
Thanks.

Comment: ![https://www.anonimg.com/uploaded-deae64e57a418631243b0d317a8d567e.png.html]